# Identifying scrolls

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

We've always played that scrolls are easily identifiable. ("Inside the chest you find 200gp and a scroll of fireball.")

Apparently we've been doing it "wrong". The [rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll) say, "If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll and cast its spell without providing any material components. Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible."

So how, by the rules, do characters identify a scroll?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Do not answer in the comments. Put your answer in the answer section. In this case, since this question is a duplicate it is not accepting any more answers. See [this Q&A](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *[identify](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/identify)*

> If it is a magic item or some other magic-imbued object, you learn its properties and how to use them,

This seems to clearly state that the *identify* spell will tell it's user what spell is in the scroll.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is a scroll actually a magic item? It seems more like a page from a spellbook. I suppose if a scroll is actually a magic item then you're right, *identify* would do it. Is that the only way? Can someone who knows the spell read the scroll and tell what it is?

Comment: @Jack: Spell scrolls are under the list of magic items in the DMG (and on DNDBeyond: https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll).